# Как реализовать правильную архитектуру классов используя паттерны проектирования?

Tags: php, laravel, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Стоит задача разработать систему оповещения в социальные сети. То есть при публикации объявления на сайт по определенным группам в вк, в инст директ, на email. Групп по каждой соц сети может быть много. Рассылка должна отправлять оповещение в очереди Laravel.
Как разработать подобную архитектуру на PHP Laravel используя шаблоны проектирования? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Делаете интерфейс, например, с методом send. И абстрактный класс для контруктора, который принимает конфиг группы. Это позволит постить в разные группы одной соц сети.

```
interface senderInterface {
   public function send($content);
}

abstract class AbstractSender{
   $config; // это однотипный коннтент который нужно разослать
   public function __construct($config){
       $this->config = $config;
   }
}
```

Потом классы для каждой социальной сети:

```
class OkSender extend AbstractSender implements sender{
     public function send($content){
        тут отправка в ок
     }
}

class VkSender extend AbstractSender implements sender{
     public function send($content){
        тут отправка в вк
     }
}
```

Можно создать массив с этими классами, а можно какой то класс обработчик.

Массив:

```
$content = 'У нас новое объявленеи, ссылка...';
$senders=[
 ['class' => OkSender::class, 'config' => ['group_id' => 666 ] ], 
 ['class' => VkSender::class, 'config' => ['group_id' => 666 ]],
 ['class' => VkSender::class, 'config' => ['group_id' => 667 ]]
]

foreach($senders as $senderRow){
   $sender = new $senderRow['class']($senderRow['config']);
   $sender->send($content);
}
```

Вместо массива можно сделать обработчик. Потом использовать паттерн стратегию, правда не классика.

```
class SendersHandler{
   private $senders=[];
   public function addSender(senderInterface  $sender){
    $this->senders[]=$sender;
   }
   public function send($content){
      foreach($this->senders  as $sender){
         $sender->send($content);
      }
   }
}

$handler = new SendersHandler();
$handler->addSender(new VkSender($config1));
$handler->addSender(new VkSender($config2));
$handler->addSender(new OkSender($config3));
$handler->send($content);
```

Если брать очереди Laravel, то лучше всего - чтобы sender был Job`ом.

```
class OkSender extends AbstractSender implements ShouldQueue, senderInterface
{
     public function send($content)
    {
        тут отправка в ок
    }
}

class VkSender extends AbstractSender implements ShouldQueue, senderInterface
{
     public function send($content)
    {
        тут отправка в Vk
    }
}

abstract class AbstractSender
{
    //Трейты Джобов по доке Ларавел
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $config; // конфиг соц сети
    public $content; // это однотипный контент который нужно разослать
    public function __construct($config, $content)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->send($this->content);
    }

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
}

class SendersHandler
{
    private $senders = [];

    public function addSender(senderInterface $sender)
    {
        $this->senders[] = $sender;
    }

    public function send($content)
    {
        foreach ($this->senders as $sender) {
            $sender->setContent($content)
            dispatch($sender);
        }
    }
}

Потом можно в провайдере забиндить класс Обработчика:

class SendersServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
    $this->app->singleton(SendersHandler::class, function ($app) {
         $handler = new SendersHandler();
         $handler->addSender(new VkSender($config1));
         $handler->addSender(new VkSender($config2));
         $handler->addSender(new OkSender($config3));
         return $handler;
         });
      }
  }
```

Это позволит в любом месте кода просто делать

```
app(SendersHandler::class)->send($content);
```

Чтобы отправит Jobы  одной строчкой.

Comment: А что за паттерн используется?

Comment: Никакого. Полиморфизм. Можно использовать стратегию, если прикрутить класс обработчик вместо массива. Сейчас дополню. Обработчик же можно потом закинуть как обсервер (или как ивент/событие)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев дополнил свои мысли по Laravel Job

Answer (score 4):

Шаблоны проектирования это типовые решения типовых проблем. Соответственно, сперва должна быть проблема. Когда вы столкнётесь с проблемой и распознаете её
как типовую, то сможете использовать шаблон. Сейчас у вас нет кода, нет диаграмм, есть только требования. Начните разработку!
Нарисуйте [диаграммы последовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и [классов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) -- определите что и как у вас будет взаимодействовать. Если вы заметите какие-то проблемы в том, что
нарисовали, тогда применяйте подходящий шаблон.

Шаблоны ради шаблонов никому не нужны. Как разработчик вы должны знать о шаблонах проектирования (для этого внимательно почитайте хотя бы Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования ISBN:978-5-4461-1213-5), но вы должны применять их **осознано** для решения **конкретных** проблем.

Обратите внимание, что ларавель сам по себе полон шаблонов проектирования. Если вам нужны шаблоны для галочки, то они уже есть в вашем фрэймворке :-)